# Session array not unset

Tags: php, session

I want to unset session array but It is not happening.
Where am I wrong in this?

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_POST['processorder']))
{

    $chk = $_SESSION['id'];

    $query="update order_details set process_order='1' where id IN(".implode(',',$chk).")";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    unset($chk);

}
```

Comment: You need to unset the `$_SESSION` and not the `$chk`

Comment: @thank you Felipe... I just stuck around because of its urgent.. Btw thanks..

Comment: @thank you Felipe... I just stuck around because of its urgent.. Btw thanks..

Comment: Do you know that your code will not work in PHP 7 (future version of PHP) and that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since a long time ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$chk = $_SESSION['id'];
```

What you're doing here is creating a variable `$chk` with the value `$_SESSION['id']` then unsetting this `$chk` but you've never touched the $_SESSION var.

To do so you need to have the following code :

```
$_SESSION['id'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['id']);
```

Answer (score 2):

use php `unset` like that :-

```
unset($_SESSION['id']);
unset($_SESSION['processorder']);
```

or you can use `session_destroy()`

> will delete ALL data associated with that user.

Not this `unset($chk);`

Answer (score 0):

`$chk` is just a **reference varialble**. You need to `unset` the original variable.

```
unset($_SESSION['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`NULL`** and **`unset`** to remove the saved values in `$_SESSION[]` variables, like:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = NULL;
unset($_SESSION['id']);
```

If you put

```
$_SESSION['id'] = '';
```

and *in case*  there is **space** in between `''` two *quotes*, then

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){}
```

returns **true** instead of **false**.

**NOTE:** You can also use **`session_destroy()`** function, but it **destroy** all saved session data.

Answer (score 0):

Unsetting `$chk` doesn't actually affect the original array. You could use references to do that. But keep in mind that unsetting a reference itself doesn't affect the original array either. This should work:

```
$session = &$_SESSION;
unset($session[id']);
```

This could be useful if you need to perform a number of actions on the $_SESSION - should make your code a bit more readable